# Solution of the Yang-Baxter equation not coming from quasi-triangular structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-field-theory, quantum-groups

Let $A$ be an associative, unital algebra over a field $\Bbbk$, and let $R \in A \otimes A$ be an invertible element which is a solution of the Yang-Bater equation in $A \otimes A \otimes A$  $$R_{12}R_{13}R_{23}=R_{23}R_{13}R_{12}.$$
Does $R$ come from a quasi-triangular structure on $A$? That is, does it exist a bialgebra structure on $A$ such that the pair $(A,R)$ is a quasi-triangular bialgebra?